# Why do my (ASP.NET MVC) links break after I move from http to https?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https

What can I do to make the links in my site work now that the url has changed from http to https? I believe the links go to http but I can't figure out how to change it in Visual Studio. It is a ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I am using Visual Studio 2012 to build it. The issue comes from a link that gets sent to the user after they register, they click on it and it is supposed to return the user to the site and tell them their account is now active. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: So unfortunately im not sure what code to use to give more content. I was told I need to make sure all links follow the same protocol as the root URL, but I don’t know how to find that in my code…also I was told That the confirmation link I’m using is "http:", but it needs to be "https:" and the Best way to fix that would be to check for http/https in the controller before sending the email, and use the correct one. I don’t understand where in my code I can find what I need to change.
Any help or guidance would be really appreciated, thank you so much in advance.